# Flutter FireBase Storage setup .......... can't even build empty project

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter

I have watched every YouTube video and I can't get right
I followed the firebase docs step by step
still it gives me this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNAF3.png)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_storage:javaPreCompileRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_storage:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find firebase-common.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/17.0.0/firebase-common-17.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           46.4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help.

Comment: make sure you're connected to the internet and try building again.should work.

Comment: I did ..
I even tried using a VPN

Answer (score 0):

I lowered the version of Flutter storage package to 3.0.0 and it works fine.